# making vertices follow along a straight line

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make something following a blueprint, I've angled the object following the side of the blueprint but now when I try make the front of the blueprint I don't know how to move it so it follows the straight line of vertices.
Thanks to anyone who helps :D[image]

Comment: You can press G then X, Y or Z to lock move on selected axis, you can even change origin by changing Global to Normal for example.

Comment: Try using G twice and then hold Alt

Comment: I agree with @LukeD. That's what I usually do.

Comment: Cheers for the answer's guys, LukeD and Ron Proctor the object is angled so when I lock it to an axis it moves it on that axis but I want to move it down without sticking out of the object

Comment: Cheers Denis for the answer but it locked on the wrong way, anyway of fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Try changing your [transformation orientation](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html) to **local** or **normal** or even you can try **view** but then you have to align the camera to the object.

Comment: Cheers m8 problem solved :D